# Simple scatter plot in R not working

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame "myframe":

```
> myframe
myframe
   exp obs
8    6  10
9    7  11
10   7  10
12   7   9
17   9   8
29   7   8
31   7   7
37   5   5
43   9  12
```

and I want to plot the two columns.

```
plot(myframe$exp,myframe$obs)
```

and I get
[image]

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Here is the output of dput(myframe):

```
> dput(myframe)
dput(myframe)
structure(list(exp = c(6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 9L), obs = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 3L), .Label = c("10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", 
"23", "25", "5", "7", "8", "9", "b", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("exp", 
"obs"), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 17L, 29L, 31L, 37L, 43L
), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: That's not what I get. Please provide the output of dput(c)

Comment: You really shouldn't call a dataset 'c' as c is already a very important function.

Comment: I think `plot(c$exp, as.numeric(paste(c$obs)))` will look like you expect but it's probably not a very good solution.

Comment: changed name to "myframe". see edited question. still same problem.

Comment: ok. with your edit, it would be `plot(myframe$exp, as.numeric(paste(myframe$obs))`

Comment: it's a problem with levels, but I don't use levels/factors so I can't help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

obs is being treated as a factor right now.  You can convert it to numeric using the following code

```
myframe$obs <- as.numeric(levels(myframe$obs))[myframe$obs]
```

Plotting should work just fine now.

Comment: What about this error message: In eval.with.vis(expr, envir, enclos) : NAs introduced by coercion. Is it okay?

Comment: That's why I used paste. ;-) It's just a warning though.  But, c$obs <- as.numeric(paste(c$obs)) won't give a warning

Comment: The method I used is the one recommended in the help page for factor.  From "?factor": In particular, ‘as.numeric’ applied to a factor is meaningless, and may happen by implicit coercion.  To transform a factor ‘f’ to approximately its original numeric values, ‘as.numeric(levels(f))[f]’ is recommended and slightly more efficient than ‘as.numeric(as.character(f))’.